# Backbone.js - Creating models and collections for entities having two-way relationships

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

I am trying to build a simple student listing app using Backbone.js which will allow users to view:

1. All the students of a university.
2. All the courses available.
3. All the students enrolled for a particular course.
4. All the courses in which a particular student is enrolled.

So, I created the following four REST endpoints to fetch these data:

```
/students
/courses
/courses/{courseId}/students
/students/{studentId}/courses
```

So, here I have a two-way relationship between the students and courses as a student can be enrolled in multiple courses and multiple students can be enrolled in a particular course.

I am trying to figure out the different backbone models and collections that I need to create. I have created the following models and collections:

```
var Student = Backbone.model.extend({
});

var Students = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Student,
  url: '/students'
});

var Course = Backbone.Model.extend({
});

var Courses = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Course,
  url: '/courses'
});
```

These can be used to fetch all the students and all the courses but what should be my models/collections for the other two endpoints?

For fetching all students for a course, I will need to add `Students` collection to a `Course` model and for fetching all courses for a student, I will need to add `Courses` collection to a `Student` model, which is not a good design. Should I have separate collections `StudentCourses` and `CourseStudents` for this?

Comment: You can have an array of courses in the student model, and have a method on students collection that accepts a course id and returns all student models enrolled for that course.